# How to set shadow on image on React Native

Tags: react-native, shadow

I want to add shadow to react-native image tag in android, where as elevation property doesn't work in Image tag style.

```
Image style={{ elevation: 1 }} source="menu" resizeMode="contain" />
```

I have encapsulated it in a view and added elevation but I get shadow of a box.

```
<View style={{
    elevation: 1,
    borderWidth: 0.1
   }}>
    <Image source="menu" resizeMode="contain" />
</View>
```

[image: Image with shadow]

but I want shadow to appear on each line of the menu image like this

[image]

Comment: you can create the icon on your own if you want it like that.  brother

Comment: You cant add shadows between the image itself. you can only add shadow to the outsides of and image. It's like that everywhere I think

Comment: solution 1)
You can replicate that shape with 3 views with border-radius and create drop shadows for each View tag.
solution 2)
You can use SVG, like "react-native-SVG" to create the shapes and create shadows according to shapes.
There is no way to create drop-shadows for PNG images. And using PNG images for icons looks pixelated and muddy on low resolution-phones. Always go with the SVG for the icons.
Hope it helps.

Comment: @MuratSerdarAkkuş Sad we can't do this for images, anyway thank you for the svg tip, I'll keep in mind.